# How to configure eclipse to run angularjs

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

i have to run angularjs in eclipse. how do i configure eclipse ide.
 I have installed AngularJs plugin from eclipse Market. but still not able to run AngularJs. Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Eclipse doesn't provide a `Run As`, because your Web Application can be managed with any HTTP Server (Tomcat, Jetty, WebSphere, etc).

If you wish to have a `Run As`, I suggest you that you transform your project to a WTP Eclipse `Dynamic Web Project`.